# webpage won't work unless I add .html to the end of it

Tags: html, cpanel, godaddy-api

This may be a dumb question, but after I load my webpages through GoDaddy's cPanel, every page won't work unless it has a .html at the end of it. Am I doing something wrong when I'm uploading it? It doesn't seem normal to need .html at the end of every page.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the "page won't work" statement? An "It doesn't work" statement is never a good description of a problem. Try to say what actually happens. Also, are you talking about pure HTML files here? or PHP files for instance?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. It gives me a File Not Found 404 error. They're pure HTML pages and after they're uploaded if I don't type them in as website.com/webpage.html they turn up with that error.

Comment: Final clarifications: 1. Do the files you upload have the .html extension? 2. Are you using Apache as the webserver?

Answer (score 1):

I might not have asked the question as clearly as I should. I ended up figuring out the answer regarding removing the .html from the webpage url.

Create a file called .htaccess in the root directory and add this code:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

And then all the links on your site should look like this:

```
<a href="/portfolio">
```

Answer (score 0):

The files are probably written in HTML which is the most common. So if you are making new windows you must add .html at the back so the browser knows it needs to read html code and not something else. So if you were to make an "about us" page you need to save it as about-us.html